# Angular js two way data binding with function

Tags: angularjs

This is my code

index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"</script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <label>Who is your favorite player</label><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="handle"/>
        <hr/>
        <h1>Favorite Player - {{ lchandle }}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp" , []);
var controller = myApp.controller( 'mainController' , [ '$scope' , '$filter' , function( $scope , $filter )
{

    $scope.handle = "";

    var tolower = function(){
        return $filter('lowercase')($scope.handle);
    }

    $scope.lchandle = tolower();

}]);
```

The favorite player does update when I change in the input

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What is the problem you are facing? Is it that `lchandle` does not update when you change `handle`?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding a $watch for the variable and variable

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp" , []);
var controller = myApp.controller( 'mainController' , [ '$scope','$filter' , function( $scope , $filter ) 
{
 $scope.$watch('handle', function() {
     $scope.handle =  $filter('lowercase')($scope.handle);

  });
 
   
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"</script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <label>Who is your favorite player</label><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="handle"/>
        <hr/>
        <h1>Favorite Player - {{ handle }}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your demo changes the input field model to lowercase. OP used a different variable for the purpose of not modifying the original one

Answer (score 0):

Based on [previous answer by Sajeetharan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48861550/3368498) I made version with `ng-change`, which I think is easier to figure out and more *modern*.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp" , []);
var controller = myApp.controller( 'mainController' , [ '$scope','$filter' , function( $scope , $filter ) 
{
 $scope.lowercase = function() {
     $scope.lhandle =  $filter('lowercase')($scope.handle);

  };
 
   
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"</script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <label>Who is your favorite player</label><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="handle" ng-change="lowercase()"/>
        <hr/>
        <h1>Favorite Player - {{ lhandle }}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your demo changes the input field model to lowercase. OP used a different variable for the purpose of not modifying the original one

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function instance, instead of its result after calling it. So change it from `$scope.lchandle = tolower();` to `$scope.lchandle = tolower;`.

Then you can call (execute) it with `<h1>Favorite Player - {{ lchandle() }}</h1>`

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
var controller = myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.handle = "";
  var tolower = function() {
    return $filter('lowercase')($scope.handle);
  }
  $scope.lchandle = tolower;
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <label>Who is your favorite player</label><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="handle" />
    <hr/>
    <h1>Favorite Player - {{ lchandle() }}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Unless you are planning to change your filter, I suggest to use a different syntax for filters:

```
<h1>Favorite Player - {{ handle | lowercase }}</h1>
```